# Insert contents inside an iframe tag

Tags: html, iframe

I want to add contents inside an iframe tag like

```
<iframe>
    <p>Hello World</p>
</iframe>
```

I tried to do that but "Hello World" does not appear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use javascript or better jQuery?

Comment: The point of an iframe is to load an external document. Why are you using an iframe if you have the content in the current document?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<iframe srcdoc="<p>Hello world!</p>" >

</iframe>
```

It will work. But Its not a good technique.